# How to invoke CompletableFuture callback while propagating result or error?

Tags: java, completable-future

I was trying .exceptionally and .handle but those don't seem to work.  In scala, you can call a method on the future with a closure that is just like a finally block(it runs on exception AND on success) AND it propogates the exception or success up the chain as-is.

I tried this...

```
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = newFuture.handle((r, e) -> {
        if(r != null)
            return r;
        else if(e != null)
            return e;
        else
            return new RuntimeException("Asdf");            
    });

    Assert.assertTrue(future.isCompletedExceptionally());
```

but that test fails as the future completely successfully with a result of exception(how weird).

Comment: To properly propagate exceptions in `handle()`, you need to `throw` them. Otherwise, the answer stating you should use `whenComplete` if you just want side effects without transforming the result is the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`CompletableFuture#whenComplete(BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-). Its javadoc states

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` **with the same result or exception** as
>   this stage, that executes the given action when this stage completes.
>
> When this stage is complete, the given action is invoked with the
>   result (or `null` if none) and the exception (or `null` if none) of this
>   stage as arguments. The returned stage is completed when the action
>   returns. If the supplied action itself encounters an exception, then
>   the returned stage exceptionally completes with this exception unless
>   this stage also completed exceptionally.

In other words, it will be invoked regardless of success or failure and will propagate the initial future's state (unless the `BiConsumer` throws an exception).

```
CompletableFuture<String> future2 = newFuture.whenComplete((r, e) -> {
    // consume the result
});
```

If you needed to transform the result (in your example, you don't), then you could use `handle` and propagate things yourself.

Answer (score 2):

ohhhhh, I think I got it....something like this seems to work

```
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future2 = newFuture.handle((r, e) -> {

        //put finally like logic right here....

        if(r != null)
            return r;
        else if(e != null)
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("weird");
    });
```