# Throw an exception within / after completable future

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, java-8, completable-future

I have a list of completable futures like this:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyObject>> futures = class_list.stream()
    .map(c -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        try { 
            return helper(c);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw th; // doesn't work
        }
    ))
    .exceptionally(ex -> {
       throw ex; // also didn't work
    }
```

And then I loop through my futures and trying to throw an exception again:

```
futures.stream.map(f -> {
   try {
     return f.get();
   }catch(Completionexception ex){
      throw new ex; (also didn't work)
   }
```

Ideally I want to exit the entire async process when a throwable exception is found.

Comment: Note that `throw new ex;` is simply incorrect Java syntax (`new` wants a constructor). Maybe you wanted `throw ex`. Beside that, what you can't do is throw a checked exception. Try wrapping it in a runtime exception (like `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` (or a custom unchecked exception type). Another thing you may want to do is replace `.get()` calls with `.join()`, which doesn't throw a checked exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke CompletableFuture callback while propagating result or error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187368/how-to-invoke-completablefuture-callback-while-propagating-result-or-error)

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for a construct like

```
try { 
    return helper(c);
}catch(Throwable th) {
   throw th;
}
```

as the behavior of catching and just re-throwing an exception is not different to not catching the exception in the first place. Likewise, chaining an `.exceptionally(ex -> { throw ex; }` would be pointless if it was legal. (It isn’t, as `Throwable` is a checked exception.

If helper doesn’t throw checked exceptions, you could simply use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> helper(c))`. Otherwise, you have to wrap checked exceptions into unchecked exceptions; the most natural choice here would be `CompletionException`.

This would look like:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyObject>> futures = class_list.stream()
    .map(c -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        try { 
            return helper(c);
        } catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new CompletionException(th);
        }
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your second operation is quiet sloppy. The class name is `CompletionException`, not `Completionexception`. Further, throwing an existing exception stored in a variable `ex` is done via `throw ex;`, not `throw new ex;`. But as already said, when you want the exception to be (re)throw, just don’t catch it in the first place.

The problem is that `get` throws the checked `ExecutionException` rather than the unchecked `CompletionException`. For the latter, you have to use `join`. So you can achieve the intended re-throwing via

```
 // will throw when any future completed exceptionally
futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```